# What is the correct statement for a SQL WHERE Clause for finding a specific number format?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a MS SQL WHERE Clause to find a specific number format from a bunch of texts, basically:
a 4 digit number that may or may not start and end on anything but a number with trailing spaces on both ends.

I am using this but it does not seem to work:

```
WHERE description LIKE '% [^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9] %'
```

Sample Data that should work:

```
THIS IS A TEST 1234 THIS IS A TEST  
THIS IS A TEST (1234) THIS IS A TEST  
THIS IS A TEST A1234B THIS IS A TEST
```

Sample data that should NOT work:

```
THIS IS A TEST 12345  
THIS IS A TEST12345THIS IS A TEST  
THIS IS A TEST NO.1234 THIS IS A TEST
```

Comment: Please show some sample data that doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated some data that I can think of

Comment: You first example definitely does not match 'space', 'non number', 'four numbers' but the next two do. Is that your expectation? 'does not seem to work' is an incomplete definition of your issue.

Comment: its 'space' then may or may not followed by any character but a number

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I could get your test cases to work:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
VALUES
(1,'THIS IS A TEST 1234 THIS IS A TEST '),
(2,'THIS IS A TEST (1234) THIS IS A TEST'),
(3,'THIS IS A TEST A1234B THIS IS A TEST'),
(4,'THIS IS A TEST 12345'),
(5,'THIS IS A TEST12345THIS IS A TEST'),
(6,'THIS IS A TEST NO.1234 THIS IS A TEST')
) A(id,description)
WHERE (
description LIKE '% [^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9] %' OR
description LIKE '% [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %'
)
```